# In which order are the queries from mod_jk redirected in apache2?

Tags: filter, apache2, mod-jk, authz

I want to allow queries from localhost to one url, and forward everything else to another service. Before I was doing this without the localhost requierement and it was working. But now it seems that although the localtion filter matches as shown with a granted message using the trace logs from `authz_core:trace8` it redirects to the service I don't want to:

```
45         <Location /api/link1/>
46             JkMount Service1
47             <RequireAny>
48                 Require local
50             </RequireAny>
51         </Location>
52        # JkMount /api/link1/* Service1
53
55         JkMount /api Service2
56         JkMount /api/* Service2
```

So given this configuration I understand that I say that if the query goes to `/api/link1` it should redirect the query to my Service1, and everything else with `/api*` should go to the Service2.

What is the reason that I'm getting the queries from `/api/link1` into the Service2 and before adding the location requisite as shown in the commented line 52 it was working?

Answer (score 0):

You should try doing this way:

```
    <Location /api/link1/>
         JkMount Service1
         <RequireAny>
             Require local
         </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    # JkMount /api/link1/* Service1

     JkMount /api Service2
     JkMount /api/* Service2
     JKUnMount /api/link1 Service2
```

I allways have had the feeling that JkMount outside any `Location` or `LocationMatch` like tags are handled before any other statement